# Class path error using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've built a fat jar using version 2.10.4 of scala, but it'll be running in on Amazon's EMR which has scala 2.11.1.

When I copy the jar (created using the `assembly` plugin) onto the EMR cluster and run it with `java -jar my.jar`, I get the expected output (scopt, the command line parser, tells me that there are missing arguments).

When I run it using `scala my.jar` I get the same thing. This is the same if I run the jar on the master or the slave nodes.

However, when I run it using `spark-submit my.jar` I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scopt.Read$.seqRead(Lscopt/Read;)Lscopt/Read;
```

So for some reason, using `spark-submit`, it can't find scopt, even if I pass `--master local`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you download the scopt library from maven [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.scopt/scopt_2.10) and add the jars externally with the spark-submit.

example :

```
spark-submit \
    [your other options here] \
    --jars $(echo ./jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
    --target yourapp.jar
```

Of course the `jars`directory is where you've actually put your dependencies (libraries).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either. I downloaded both the 2.10 and 2.11 jars and separately invoked spark-submit, but with the same outcome. I even called `setJars` in code as per http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting but still no luck. If I remove scopt, it works, but it's pretty inconvenient having to recompile the jar each time I want to invoke it with different arguments...

Comment: Then you'll have to downgrade Amazon EMR's Scala to 2.10.x because spark isn't 2.11.x ready yet.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with 2.10 vs 2.11 because I can run the jar successfully on the master and worker which both have 2.11. I think it's a weirder issue with spark setting the class path. I think I'll probably just ditch scopt in favour of a different CLI parser library...

Comment: That can be a good approach. I haven't tried it! Let me know it works for you.

Comment: EMR Spark already uses Scala 2.10. See https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/README.md

Comment: I suspected that considering that Spark isn't compatible with scala 2.11.x for cross-compilation issues.